# How to change the color of the dropdown icon on the right of SectionedMultiSelect - react-native-sectioned-multi-select

Tags: react-native, colors, dropdown

I want to change the color of the dropdown icon on the right of SectionedMultiSelect from the default color. Here is my code:

```
          <SectionedMultiSelect
              items={items}
              IconRenderer={Icon}
              uniqueKey="id"
              // subKey="children"
              selectText="Click to select Expertise"
              showDropDowns={true}
              onSelectedItemsChange={(selectedItems) => {
                setDidUpdate(true);
                setExpertise(selectedItems)
              }}
              selectedItems={expertise}
              colors= {{
                primary: 'red'
              }}
              styles={{
                // chipText: {
                //   maxWidth: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 90,
                // },
                chipContainer : {
                  // backgroundColor: 'red',
                  // color: 'green',
                  borderRadius: 16,
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: 'white',
                  marginTop: 10
                },
                chipText: {
                  color: 'white',
                },
                chipIcon: {
                  color: 'white',
                },
                button: {
                  backgroundColor: '#FF9017',
                },
                selectToggle: {
                  color: 'white',
                },
                selectToggleText: {
                  color: 'white',
                  // backgroundColor: 'red',
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderRadius:25,
                  borderColor: '#fff',
                  padding: 5,
                  paddingLeft: 15
                },
              }}
            />
```

I have tried changing it through the styles and the color props but to no avail.

Comment: you can use like this =>                                                                                                              const renderIcon = (selected, highlighted) => {
    const iconName = selected ? 'arrow-circle-down' : 'downhill-skiing';
    const iconColor = highlighted ? 'green' : 'black'; 
    return <Icon name={iconName} size={24} color={iconColor}/>;
  };                                                                                                                    
  pass this function inside <SectionedMultiSelect IconRenderer={renderIcon}  ... />